# Parse JSON payload with a Date field In a Specific Format

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a class like this

```scala
case class Foo(name : String, date : LocalDate)
```

and a codec defined as:

```scala
implicit val codec = Json.format[Foo]
```

I am looking for a way to specify that the date should be in a specific format and if not then the read of the JSON to the class fails. Is this possible?

What I did was to use require like this:

```scala
case class Foo(name : String, date : LocalDate) {
require(isValid(date), "bad format")
}

object Foo {
def isValid(date : LocalDate) : Boolean = {
 // parse date and throw exception if not in right format
}
```

```
object Foo {
  val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")

  def toLocalDate(dateStr: String): LocalDate =
    LocalDate.parse(dateStr, dateFormatter)

  def formatDate(date: LocalDate): String =
    date.format(dateFormatter)

  implicit val localDateFormat: Format[LocalDate] =
    Format(
      JsPath.read[String].map(toLocalDate), (dateTime : LocalDate) => JsString(formatDate(dateTime))
    )


  implicit val format: OFormat[Foo] = Json.format[Foo]
}
```

Comment: please upvote if my answer helped you - and/or accept it if my answer solved your problem - or let a comment if you still stuck - or provide your answer if you solved it differently - thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use `play-json` you can add a formatter for `LocalDate`, like

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

import play.api.libs.json._

object DateHelper {

implicit val localDateFormat: Format[LocalDate] =
  Format(
    JsPath.read[String].map(toLocalDate),
    dateTime => JsString(formatDate(dateTime))
  )
...
```

Here are the helpers:

```
val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")

def toLocalDate(dateStr: String): LocalDate =
  LocalDate.parse(dateStr, dateFormatter)

def formatDate(date: LocalDate): String =
  date.format(dateFormatter)
```

`toLocalDate` can throw an exception, `formatDate` not.

Make sure `DateHelper` is in Scope:

```
import DateHelper._

object Foo {
  implicit val codec = Json.format[Foo]
}
```

Comment: I get this error; [error]  found   : java.time.LocalDate => play.api.libs.json.JsString
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.Writes[java.time.LocalDate]
[error]       JsPath.read[String].map(toLocalDate), (dateTime : LocalDate) => JsString(formatDate(dateTime))

Comment: have you added `DateHelper` to the scope?

Comment: I added the helpers inside the DateHelper

Comment: I adjusted my answer - to be sure that you understand my point - did you have that?

Comment: but all the code is inside object Foo so I dont need to import right?

Comment: `implicit val localDateFormat: Format[LocalDate]` is in the `DateHelper`, so you have to import it as shown in my answer

Comment: yes but I am not putting it inside DateHelper, I have put it iinside Object Foo so it should pick it up.